# Strange NFS Issue

Tags: mount, nfs

Hoping someone can help with this.

I've got an issue where I've got a mounted directory with three sub directories. I'm able to CD into two of the sub directories without any issue, however the third gives "permission denied" even when I'm the root user.

If I log in as the owner, I'm able to CD in, however I'm confused as to why the root user can't access the directory. UID'S AND GID's on the NFS server and mounted server are the same.

I've tried to remount the directories but problem still persists.

Comment: Have all three subdirectories the same owner, group and permissions?

Comment: root is often denied access to exported NFS dir unless you set `access` option in export file. see `man 5 exports`.

Comment: The official option to handle root access is: `root=list` where `list` is a colon separated list of hostnames, see `man share_nfs`.

Comment: @schily -- that is a vendor-specific option, too. There is nothing 'official  about the solaris implementation of NFS.

Comment: Well, it is the reference implementation.

Comment: Not the same thing, even if it were true (which I doubt)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux NFS, the default these days is to enable the `root_squash` server-side option. This means the server will remap the root uid to something else, usually `nobody`. If you don't want that, add the option `no_root_squash` to your exports file on the server.

If you're not root on the server, then this behaviour is a feature, not a bug :-)

Comment: `root:squash` is not an option available by NFS in eneral but it is a vendor unique deviation from the official NFS options.

Comment: Yes, a linux specific option. It's fair to guess that the OP is using Linux, but okay

Answer (score 0):

If root would be given the permission you expect, then NFS would be extremely insecure.

Root thus can only overwrite local permissions as people who have root privileges usually have other ways to access files as well (e.g. by reading the raw device.

Root via NFS is mapped to `nobody` by default. Nobody for NFSv3 is user id 60001, and 65534 for NFS2.

For trusted hosts, there is a way to enable root access by e.g. setting `root=thishost` in the NFS export options. More hosts may be appended separated by colons.

Note that for NFSv4, things are different as NFSv4 gives access based on user names instead of user ids. As a result, even a user with the right user id is not given access permissions unless there is a user map or the server and the client are using the same network naming service domain.